# Ferrite bead in USB

Tags: microcontroller, pic, usb, design

Is the Ferrite Bead really necessary in a USB project?

I want a general answer so I might learn, but in my case, I am using a PIC18F2550 Full Speed USB.

Comment: What "the" ferrite bead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not to get it working, but it might be very useful if you care about electro(magnetic?) pollution *out of your device* into the wider world, especially if you need some sort of approval.

Comment: How will it prevent it?

Comment: @mFeinstein The ferrite bead is basically wire wrapped through [ferrite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrite_%28magnet%29) core. That core has almost same behavior as the one you can see inside the transformer: It increases inductance of the wire. Since for inductors, impedance is \$Z=R+j \omega L\$ and R in beads is relatively low, we get a filter which removes high frequency components and passes through low frequency components. The pollution is usually caused by high-frequency signals, so once we remove them, they can't spread out and contaminate other devices.

Comment: Just to make it clear, which is the usual frequency cut range?

Comment: it's very dynamic mFeinstin, you need a spectrum analyzer and decide yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The ferrite bead in general serves two purposes:

1) EMI filtering to ensure that the VCC coming to your circuit is more filtered, ande perhaps that nothing gets back to the USB port from your circuit

2) As a very simple fuse since the ferrite bead has a current spec. I am not sure whether ferrite beads blow like a normal fuse in this case.

Comment: So it's just a complement to the capacitors I already have..

Comment: Yes,the capacitors help as well. Is there an issue why you don't want to use the ferrite bead? It's not very expensive.

Comment: Never heard of a ferrite bead blowing in any normal use! Exceed its current rating and you could saturate it - it won't filter so well when saturated, but it recovers when the current drops.

Comment: @GustavoLitovsky I just finished a PCB, and I dont have much space left, so to include it, I will need to redesign it and USB is not the major role of it, just a configuration interface...so I think in case something goes very wrong it will be in version 2.0 :D

Comment: For the current version, just cut the trace with something, leaving a milimeter, then mount it. Otherwise, shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: Coming from the future to save someone headache - a ferrite bead is absolutely not a fuse and should not be relied on as one. The current limit is a soft limit, it will happily handle a significant amount more and that is not controlled. Use a polyfuse if you need current limiting, not a ferrite bead (or inductor or resistor for that matter) with a current/power limit.

Answer (score 2):

Tests have shown that it is necessary to carefully decouple both VBUS and Gnd. This is done with ferrite beads. Separate ferrite beads may be used on each VBUS line to each downstream USB connector. Each ferrite bead on the VCC lines should be rated at 500 ma. Separate ferrites are useful, not only for EMI suppression, but also for their series DC resistance which limits the inrush current during a hot plug event.